# Symbols and Signs by A.J. Ayer

Tags: logic, linguistics, logical-positivism

This is from Ayer's "Language, truth and logic":

> A factor which complicates the structure of a language such as English is the prevalence of ambiguous symbols. A symbol is said to be ambiguous when it is constituted by signs which are identical in their sensible form, not only with one another, but also with signs which are elements of some other symbol. For what makes two signs elements of the same symbol is not merely an identity of form, but also an identity of usage. Thus, if we were guided merely by the form of the sign, we should assume that the ‘is’ which occurs in the sentence ‘He is the author of that book’ was the same symbol as the ‘is’ which occurs in the sentence ‘A cat is a mammal’. But, when we come to translate the sentences, we find that the first is equivalent to ‘He, and no one else, wrote that book’, and the second to ‘The class of mammals contains the class of cats’. And this shows that, in this instance, each ‘is’ is an ambiguous symbol which must not be confused with the other, nor with the ambiguous symbols of existence, and class-membership, and identity, and entailment, which are also constituted by signs of the form ‘is’.

As we can see, using author's terminology, there's 'is' as a form of the sign.

There's also 'is' as a symbol of class-membership and as a symbol of existence, etc.

All of these symbols are constructed by 'is' as a form of the sign combined with some special use of this sign (to show class-membership in one case or to show existence in another case, etc.).

In the text is also said that symbol can be constituted by multiple signs:

> A symbol is said to be ambiguous when it is constituted by signs which are identical in their sensible form, not only with one another, but also with signs which are elements of some other symbol.

But I don't see which sign can constitute 'is' as sign of existence besides the 'is' as a sign.

Maybe you can give an example of symbol constituted by more than one sign?

Please, remain in the stated terminology framework.

Comment: Why posting it again?

Comment: I thought that I can put the question differently. But I wasn't sure that new formulation is better. So I decided to leave two questions, because I didn't know which of them is gonna bring me an answer of the needed form.

Comment: Semiotic *symbols* is nothing else but *sign processes* which are not context-free and usually a symbol could be constituted by more than one signs, for instance, 'is said to be' as a symbol composed by several signs has more subtlety than the symbol 'is' constituted by a single sign with the first usage in your quote. Or even a whole proposition could be said to be a single symbol token or type semiotically...